# Flutter Firebase Crashlytics with flavors - XCode dSYM file upload script with dart-only initialization

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I have a Flutter project with different flavors, each flavor uses a different Firebase project.

I use dart-only initialization and don't have any `GoogleService-Info.plist` files in my project.

This works quite well except when I want to configure Firebase Crashlytics for the different flavors. In particular, the XCode build phase script that uploads the dSYM files. The default (as configured by the FlutterFire cli) script uses the Google App Id as specified in the `firebase_app_id.json` file. This way, all my flavor upload the dSYM files to one firebase project.

I tried to overwrite this build script and set my different Google App Ids based on what flavor I'm building however it seems I don't have access to the used XCode scheme in this script, so I have no idea how I can determine what Google App Id I should use.

Comment: If you have different Firebase projects for every different flavour, you can use secondary Firebase app initialization in your case.